# SAS Command Line shortcut

Tags: command-line, sas, display-manager, dm

Is there a shortcut in Base SAS to provide focus to the command-line / display manager bar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On a Windows PC, the F11 key will probably already be mapped to provide focus to the command bar, so I would suggest trying that first.  F9 as you show in the other answer is typically mapped by default (again on Windows) to show the existing key-bindings (Same as going to Tools->Options->Keys).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Trevor

dm "keydef F9 ""command focus;""";